# Enable logging in Apache Commons Net for FTP protocol

Tags: java, logging, ftp, apache-commons-net

Apache Commons Net library does not seem to send anything to any "logger".

Can I somehow obtain a log file from an (FTP) session, for debugging purposes? For example raw FTP commands and responses from the server, like this:

```
220 Welcome
USER *******
331 Password required for ...
PASS *******
230 Logged on
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
QUIT
221 Goodbye
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All protocol implementations in Apache Commons Net, including `FTPClient`, derive from [`SocketClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html), which has a method [`addProtocolCommandListener`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#addProtocolCommandListener(org.apache.commons.net.ProtocolCommandListener)). You can pass it an implementation of [`ProtocolCommandListener`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ProtocolCommandListener.html) to implement logging.

There's a ready-made implementation [`PrintCommandListener`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/PrintCommandListener.html), which prints the protocol log to provided `PrintStream`.

With a code like this:

```
ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(
    new PrintCommandListener(
        new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")), true));
```

..., you will get exactly the output that you have asked for.