# Apache FTPSCleint.listFiles() returns empty array

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I'm trying to get files from ftp server with no luck. commons-net version 3.5

```
            FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();
            ftpClient.connect("xxx.com", 21);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.login("login", "password");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig();
//            conf.setUnparseableEntries(true);
            conf.setServerTimeZoneId("UTC");
            ftpClient.configure(conf);
            ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
            ftpClient.execPROT("P");
            return ftpClient;
```

Only after I uncommented `conf.setUnparseableEntries(true)` I got array of "something". `isFile()` method returns false so I can't use `File`'s methods with it. All of them throws NullPointerException.

Any advise where is the problem and why Apache can't parse files?

*Added ftp log:*

```
220 
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
USER *******
331 Password required
PASS *******
230 User logged in.
TYPE I
200 Type set to I.
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ command successful.
PROT P
200 PROT command successful.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,200,2,87,252,174).
LIST /INCOME
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: Show us [`FTPSClient` log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848) + What do you get from `getRawListing` for those files? + Does any GUI FTP client show listing from that server?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl just added FTP log. I can't call `getRawListing` on an empty array of files.

Comment: With `setUnparseableEntries(true)`, of course.

Comment: I hoped for a complete log, so that we can see what kind of server that is.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Got something like this on every entry: `01-18-2019  03:16PM              2337813 mvk.xml`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How to get full log? I used `ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(
    new PrintCommandListener(
        new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")), true));` and posted full output.

Comment: Did you use that **before** `ftpClient.connect`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl fixed log)

Comment: OK, so it does no say anything about itself in the initial 220 welcome message -- or did you delete that part?). What does `ftpClient.getSystemType()` return?

Comment: In any case I do not think that the library can parse that format.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I didn't delete anything. `ftpClient.getSystemType()` returned `SYST
215 Windows_NT`

Comment: That looks like Microsoft IIS. But I've never seen IIS return listing like that. Do you have an access to IIS Management console? What version of Windows/IIS is that?