# apache FTP Client connection timeout when connecting to remove host

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

The tittle is duplicate but the question is different.

I am using the FTPClient[apache commons 3.6] class to connect to an FTP Server[apache ftp server 1.1.1 jar file] which was launched by code. This FTP Server was configured as follows

```
  FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

  ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
  factory.setServerAddress("/*IP Address*/");//The IPV4 Address Of My System
  factory.setPort(8001);  
  serverFactory.addListener("default",listener=factory.createListener());

   PropertiesUserManagerFactory userFactory=new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
   userFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new ClearTextPasswordEncryptor());
   BaseUser baseUser=new BaseUser();
   baseUser.setName("Test");
   baseUser.setPassword("123");
   baseUser.setEnabled(true);
   baseUser.setHomeDirectory("E:/Test Data");
   baseUser.setAuthorities(Arrays.asList(new WritePermission()));
   UserManager uManager=userFactory.createUserManager();
   serverFactory.setUserManager(uManager);      

  ftpServer=serverFactory.createServer();
  ftpServer.start();
```

And Here Is How I Connect To This Server

```
FTPClient client=new FTPClient();
client.connect("/*Same IP Address As Server*/",8001);

client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

client.logIn("Test","123");
```

The Code works fine when both server and client are in the same system but when server is an remote host I get the "ConnectionTimedOutException" when im logging in

```
client.logIn("Test","123"); //It Throws Timeout here
```

Its odd that connect() works but timesout when logging in. Any parameters to tweek here?

I tested the server with the FTPClient gui FileZela which gives me the same error when server is in remove system but works within the same system
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

Here is the stack trace for my connection code

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
```

EDIT:

I tweeked  some parameters and now I am able to login to my remote server I had To change the following parameters

```
 client.setSoTimeout(5000);   //Time To Wait For Login Operation(in milliseconds)
 client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(1); //Time Interval to send keep alive messages(in seconds)
 client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(5000);// Time to wait for an keep alive response message (in milliseconds)
```

But now my connection times out when uploading any data for example

```
 try(OutputStream toFile=client.storeFileStream("File.txt"))
 {
  toFile.write("Just Some Small Text".getBytes());
  toFile.close();
 }

 if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode()))
 {
  String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
  if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) 
  {
   StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
   for(String aReply : replies){builder.append(aReply).append(" ");}
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,builder.toString());
  } 

  //The server replies here are connection timeout no exception is thrown 
 }
```

Comment: You are wure that there is an ftp server listen on port 8001 on your remote server?

Comment: Is port 8001 blocked by a firewall perhaps?

Comment: Can you connect to your server using any (GUI) FTP client running on the same machine as your Java client code?

Comment: There is no firewall blocking my port cause that was the case before where I got an connection refused exception which was solved by disabling it. Also the server is listening on port 8001 because connect () works but not login() ,if I enter incorrect username/password it immediately returns incorrect status code but with correct credentials it times out. Yes this code works when client and server are on the same machine

Comment: I was asking if, you can you connect to your server using any **(GUI)** FTP client *(not your code)* running on the same machine as your Java **client** code *(not on the server machine)*?

Comment: yes I can both using telnet and using apache gui for ftp client

Comment: What does telnet have to do with FTP? What Apache GUI? Show us a log file from the FTP client. A [log file from your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848) might be useful too.

Comment: all the relevant information u have requested is in the edited question

Comment: If you cannot connect with any FTP client software, you do not have a programming question. Please move your problem to a relevant site, like [su].

Comment: Turns Out it might be a code problem after all. After applying the values I specified in my newEdit even in my client gui I am able to login but unable to upload. Can anyone plzz try to help me just a little more

Comment: Can you upload in the GUI client?

Comment: No. Tweeking The same parameters over there as I did in my code is what helped me to log in so I assume the code suggestions u give me here can help me find similar parameters over there to change and test

Comment: I do not think so. It's more probable that it won't work in any way. It's likely a firewall problem. First make your GUI client working.

Comment: but if it was a firewall problem then my client would not have connected at all but I have come far as to login right? Anyway I will try to make the gui work and get back to u. sometimes if i try enough times without making any changes the gui starts to work but not my code but I will try anyway

Comment: No, FTP is complicated when comes to firewalls. See my article on [FTP and firewalls and NATS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Comment: So I read up just a little of your article[will continue to read more] and I understand that a FTP client  enters passive mode to avoid firewall problems and also for this mode to work the server must have a range of passive ports available to listen on for data connections. in my server code I tried quering available passive data ports and it displayed '0'. But still my local client and server works don't understand why. What passive ports should I use for my data transfer and when should I enter passive mode? after connecting or after logging in?

Comment: If your client works locally, there's nothing wrong with your server **software**. It's the server **firewall** that blocks the data connections from other machines. Finish reading and understanding the article and then ask. At the appropriate site. So far, I do not think you have a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. This problem was an connection timeout problem which was divided into 2 parts

Q1) Timing Out when Logging In

Ans) Just had to tell the FTP Client To Wait a little longer and keep the connection alive with special control messages

Here Is The Code Sample

```
client.setConnectTimeout(5000);  //5000 ms to wait 
client.connect(ip,port);
if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode()))
{
 client.disconnect();
 return;
}
client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); //This Solves Part 2 Of My Problem

//These 3 lines of code are what solved my login problem
{
client.setSoTimeout(5000);//Wait Atleast 5 seconds for login
client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(1);//Send An Keep Alive Message every second
client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(5000);//Wait atleast 5 seconds to respond to my KeepAlive messages
}
boolean success=client.login(fields[6].getText(),fields[7].getText());
if(!success)
{
 client.disconnect();
 return;
}
```

Q2)Time Out When Uploading Data To Server

Ans)This was an server problem. Turns out i have to manually allocate passive ports for the client to send data on and later port forward them in my router settings

```
   ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
   factory.setServerAddress("localhost");
   factory.setPort(8000);  


//And This Is What solved my Data timeout problem     
{
       DataConnectionConfigurationFactory dfFactory=new   DataConnectionConfigurationFactory();
       dfFactory.setPassivePorts("8001-8005");//I Port Forward These data ports on my router web page and disable firewall for them
       factory.setDataConnectionConfiguration(dfFactory.createDataConnectionConfiguration());
}

       serverFactory.addListener("default",factory.createListener());
```

Offcourse if your network is slow u need an timeout in your client code as well

```
 client.setSoTimeout(10000);//Wait 10 seconds for upload to complete
 client.setDataTimeout(10000);//Timeout if no data transfer for 10 seconds
```