# FTPClient is returning: Cannot parse response code

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I'm receiving this when I try to retrieve a file using the FTPClient:

```
Could not parse response code.
Server Reply:
150 Opening data channel for file download from server
```

How I connected:

```
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(this.timeout);

    try {
        ftpClient.connect(this.host, this.port);
        ftpClient.setSoTimeout(this.timeout);
        if (!ftpClient.login(username, password)) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
```

The code causing the issue is:

```
    File downloadedFile = new File(localFile);

    try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile))) {

        ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream);
    }
```

When I manually download a file via FTP commands, I receive a multi line reply:

```
ftp> get file
local: file remote: file
200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/file"
226 Successfully transferred "/file"
202 bytes received in 0.00 secs (1777.2 kB/s)
```

Comment: Show us a [log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848).

Comment: I had a similar issue, in my case the protocol was changed to SFTP so the FTP client was throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the connection is closed before the transfer is finished or maybe the transfer method is invalid.

- Can you tried to download the file via Filezilla client to test if it work?
- Can you share the code you are using to connect to FTP?

I reviewed a code I write before and I got to add the following lines before downloading the file. Try this:

```java
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;

try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile))) {
    // These lines set the type of file to be binary.
    // I had some issues that the file downloaded corrupted.
    ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.setFileStructure(FTP.FILE_STRUCTURE);
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeout);

    ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream);
}
```

Also, checked out the timeout value.