# Spring Integration FTP Low Level Logging

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

DefaultFtpSessionFactory in Spring Integration FTP provides an abstraction for the underlying client API. When we need to troubleshoot, FTP connectivity and transfer issues, is it possible to configure the logs to print lower level FTP connection details.
After enabling TRACE on org.springframework we only get the messages connected to FTP site and file transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Integration FTP support is fully based on that Apache `commons-net`.
Doesn't look like the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` class we use in the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` has some logging hooks. However it is possible to inject your own `ProtocolCommandListener` into this `FTPClient`, e.g. a `PrintCommandListener`: [Enable logging in Apache Commons Net for FTP protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426062/enable-logging-in-apache-commons-net-for-ftp-protocol).

The `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` should be overridden in this case and such a `addProtocolCommandListener()` customization should be called from the `postProcessClientBeforeConnect(T client)` implementation.

Comment: Thank you Artem!

Comment: Thanks this is my code in kotlin 

class FtpSessionFactory(): DefaultFtpSessionFactory() {
    override fun postProcessClientBeforeConnect(client: FTPClient?) {
        client?.addProtocolCommandListener(PrintCommandListener(
                IoBuilder.forLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG).buildPrintWriter(), true))
    }
}