# Get files on FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I am a starter in java and I am trying to get the files in a directory on a ftp server but the array keeps coming back empty

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class listfiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "";
        String pass = "";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);

            int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Connect failed");
                return;
            }

            boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);

            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                return;
            }
            String[] files3 = ftpClient.listNames("/Test");
            System.out.println("passedit");
            printNames(files3);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printNames(String files[]) {
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (String aFile: files) {
                System.out.println(aFile);
            }
        }else
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }

    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a proftpd on a Raspberry pi
I have 2 files in that folder.
I tried changing the path to /home/pi/Test.

[Files on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ccz1.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejD4W.png)

Also can someone please explain me why it says Class transformation for 224 classes

Edit Loggs
Java code:

```
 ---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
com\.example\.myapplicationtestmenu\..*
exclude patterns:
220 ProFTPD Server (RaspberryPi) [::ffff:192.168.1.5]
SERVER: 220 ProFTPD Server (RaspberryPi) [::ffff:192.168.1.5]
USER *******
331 Password required for pi
PASS *******
230 User pi logged in
SERVER: 230 User pi logged in
PORT 192,168,1,3,110,79
200 PORT command successful
NLST /
425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out
/
-----------------------
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Filezila logs:

```
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Connecting to 192.168.1.5:21...
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 220 ProFTPD Server (RaspberryPi) [::ffff:192.168.1.5]
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 500 AUTH not understood
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: AUTH SSL
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 500 AUTH not understood
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: USER pi
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 331 Password required for pi
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: PASS *****
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 230 User pi logged in
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: SYST
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: FEAT
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-Features:
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-CLNT
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-EPRT
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-EPSV
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-HOST
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-LANG en-US.UTF-8*;en-US
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-MDTM
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-MFMT
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.groupname*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;UNIX.ownername*;
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-REST STREAM
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SITE COPY
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SITE MKDIR
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SITE RMDIR
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SITE SYMLINK
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SITE UTIME
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-SIZE
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-TVFS
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211-UTF8
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 211 End
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Logged in
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: PWD
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: TYPE I
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 200 Type set to I
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: PASV
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,5,173,181).
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Command: LIST
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete
2021-04-05 09:29:28 13760 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/Videos"...
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Command: CWD Videos
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Response: 250 CWD command successful
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Command: PWD
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Response: 257 "/Videos" is the current directory
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Command: PASV
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,5,131,57).
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Command: LIST
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete
2021-04-05 09:29:34 13760 1 Status: Directory listing of "/Videos" successful
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Command: CDUP
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Response: 250 CDUP command successful
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Command: PWD
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
2021-04-05 09:29:37 13760 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/Test"...
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Command: CWD Test
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Response: 250 CWD command successful
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Command: PWD
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Response: 257 "/Test" is the current directory
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Command: PASV
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,5,136,105).
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Command: LIST
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete
2021-04-05 09:29:39 13760 1 Status: Directory listing of "/Test" successful
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Status: Connecting to 192.168.1.5:21...
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Response: 220 ProFTPD Server (RaspberryPi) [::ffff:192.168.1.5]
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Response: 500 AUTH not understood
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Command: AUTH SSL
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Response: 500 AUTH not understood
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Command: USER pi
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Response: 331 Password required for pi
2021-04-05 09:29:42 13760 2 Command: PASS *****
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 230 User pi logged in
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Status: Logged in
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Status: Starting download of /Test/tes.pdf
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Command: CWD /Test
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 250 CWD command successful
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Command: PWD
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 257 "/Test" is the current directory
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Command: TYPE I
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 200 Type set to I
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Command: PASV
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,5,176,7).
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Command: RETR tes.pdf
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for tes.pdf (202014 bytes)
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Response: 226 Transfer complete
2021-04-05 09:29:43 13760 2 Status: File transfer successful, transferred 202,014 bytes in 1 second
```

Solved:
The problem seems to be my firewall if i take it down i can see all files on the ftp server
Or keep the firewall up and add the line             `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();`

Comment: And what happens when you use any other ftp client?

Comment: Like if i try to access it from the web with ftp://ip_addr? If i try accessing this way i see all the files. Or do you mean another code like a python code?

Comment: Show us a log file from any commandline/GUI FTP client that can see all the files + [Log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848) from your Java code. + In general, with Apache Commons Net, you need to call `enterLocalPassiveMode`.

Comment: Added filezila and java logs, seems the problem its with the java code. With the NLST command it uses to retrive files

Comment: The problem was with the firewall, i took it down and it worked but if i add the line :         ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); works like a charm with the firewall still up

Answer (score 0):

> `ftpClient.listNames("/Test")`

This is returning nothing. Double check your casing, and run both `listNames("/")` and `listNames("")` and `listNames("Test")`; one of those should work.

Comment: Just tried all three the output is empty for all the solutions, i am using the apache net example for upload and it works with the path /Test

Comment: Then the FTP server itself is just not serving files. Use something else to check.