# Why can I retrieve file names but not file objects from the FTP server?

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to access files on an FTP server embedded in specialised hardware with the Apache Commons Net library. For some reason `listNames()` works, but `listFiles()` does not.

The documentation for the hardware is very limited, but it does at least say that active mode has to be used. Connection to the hardware is made over a local WiFi network with no Internet access. The code below runs from within an Android app.

```
ftpClient.connect(FTP_IP, 21);
Log.e(TAG, "reply string after connect():" + ftpClient.getReplyString());
ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
ftpClient.enterRemoteActiveMode(InetAddress.getByName(FTP_IP), 21);
ftpClient.login(FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
Log.e(TAG, "reply string after login(): " + ftpClient.getReplyString());

ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.LIST);
Log.e(TAG, "reply string for LIST: " + ftpClient.getReplyString());

ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.NAME_LIST);
Log.e(TAG, "reply string for NLST: " + ftpClient.getReplyString());

remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles();
Log.e(TAG, "number of remote FTPFile objects returned: " + remoteFiles.length);

remoteFileNames = ftpClient.listNames();
Log.e(TAG, "remote file names returned: " + remoteFileNames);
```

The output:

```
2022-06-29 17:07:02.853 21263-22717/spinner.fakdown E/FTP: reply string after connect():220--- Welcome to *** FTP
    220---   By *** ---
    220 --   Version: 1.0 FTP-2015-04-08 - modify *** 2016-09-14 ver2   --
2022-06-29 17:07:02.875 21263-22717/spinner.f E/FTP: reply string after login(): 230 OK.
2022-06-29 17:07:02.881 21263-22717/spinner.f E/FTP: reply string for LIST: 425 No data connection
2022-06-29 17:07:02.888 21263-22717/spinner.f E/FTP: reply string for NLST: 425 No data connection
2022-06-29 17:07:03.235 21263-22717/spinner.f E/FTP: number of remote FTPFile objects returned: 0
2022-06-29 17:07:03.485 21263-22717/spinner.f E/FTP: remote file names returned: 6
```

Judging by the error code 425, I suspect that there's some issue related to active/passive mode, but can't see how to clear it.

- I have confirmed that the server is accessible and the files are browseable via the Turbo Client app on Android.
- I have tried all the different possible `FTPClientConfig` options (e.g. `FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX`).

Comment: If it was *active/passive mode issue*, the `listNames` won't work either. + Post [Apache Commons Net log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848) + It possible that the listing parser does not understand your server listing format. You mist need to configure parser for your specific server type. Or even implement your own parser. => Try `FTPClientConfig.setUnparseableEntries`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Very useful, thank you. I didn't know about that method to display the Apache Commons Net log. (By the way this reminded me to donate to WinSCP, which had been on my mind for a long time - have now done so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Prikryl's comments put me on the right track: calling `setUnparseableEntries()` caused `listFiles()` to start returning `FTPFile` objects that in turn returned usable information for `getRawListing()`.

I'd already tried `setUnparseableEntries()` but I tried it again and this time, for some reason, it worked - so it must have needed some other setting to be made (possibly `enterLocalActiveMode()`) that wasn't active at the time I initially tried it. Whatever the reason, `listFiles()` now returned a non-empty array.

I then extended `ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl` to create my own parser, so that I could use `getName()`, `getSize()` and `isDirectory()` on the `FTPFile` objects.