# Java Android Upload image to server FTPClient - Error 501 PASV: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android, ftp

When trying to upload the image to the server

`clientFtp.getReplyCode()`

returns the value of 501 and

`clientFtp.getReplyString()`

returns **501 PASV: Operation not permitted**, it reaches the validation of

`FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion`

and it returns false for which does not let me move forward, it disconnects the clientFtp and the image does not upload.
It then continues to close the input and when it reaches

`clientFtp.logout()`

This throws me into the catch and prints the following error in the Log **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**
The strange thing is that I try it with several devices and 99% if it works and 1% throws me these errors, my code is here;

```
public static class uploadFileFtp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        String absolutePath;
        String imagename;
        String binder;
        String idContrato;

        public uploadFileFtp(String absolutePath, String imagename, String binder, String idContrato) {
            this.absolutePath = absolutePath;
            this.imagename = imagename;
            this.binder = binder;
            this.idContrato = idContrato;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            FTPClient clientFtp = null;
            try{

                clientFtp = new FTPClient();

                clientFtp.connect(keys.hostname,keys.port);
                clientFtp.setSoTimeout(10000);
                clientFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                if(clientFtp.login(keys.username,keys.password)){
                    clientFtp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    clientFtp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
                    clientFtp.storeFile("/" + keys.ftp_home_folder + "/" + binder + "/" + imagename, input);
                    int reply = clientFtp.getReplyCode();
                    String replyString = clientFtp.getReplyString();
                    if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
                        clientFtp.disconnect();
                        Log.i("MESSAGE","THE SERVER DID NOT ALLOW TO CONNECT");
                    }
                    input.close();
                    clientFtp.logout();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }catch(Exception e){
                global.writeError(e, 97);
                Log.i("MESSAGE","Error: "+e);
                return false;
            }finally {
                if(clientFtp.isConnected()){
                    try{clientFtp.disconnect();}
                    catch(Exception e){
                        global.writeError(e, 98);
                        Log.i("MESSAGE","Error: "+e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean send) {
            if (send) {
                Log.i("MESSAGE", "Send");
            }else {
                Log.i("MESSAGE", "Not sent");
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Post complete exception callstack + [Log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848) + Log file of any commandline/GUI FTP client application that can successfully upload the file from the *same machine*, where your Java code fails.

Comment: If you want a help, you will have to give us the information I've asked for.

Answer (score -1):

You call logout() after disconnect().

Comment: True, but that's not the root problem, right?

Comment: It is. Dont call it after disconnecting.

Comment: No, the root problem is that the upload does not work. That OP has other problem when cleaning up the connection after failed upload is not really what OP is promarily worried about, imo.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's right, the problem is that the file is not uploaded to ftp, the response from the ```getReplyCode()``` method gives me a 501 code, when in reality it should give me a 200 or another code which tells me that the file was uploaded correctly.

Comment: When it reaches the ```clientFtp.logout()``` it throws me the following error in the Log
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

I tried to solve it by creating a new user and a new password in the ftp, but the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: Do not call logout() after disconnect().