# ftp download for small datasets works but for more than 300KB not

Tags: docker, download, ftp

I am trying to download a file from my ftp server. As soon as the file is larger than 300KB, the download fails. Below that limit, it works. The ftp server is running in a Docker container (image: delfer/alpine-ftp-server). Here is my method:

```java
public InputStream getInputStreamFromURI(String uri) throws IOException {
        try {
            ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(
                    new PrintWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")), true));
            assureConnection(false);
            ftp.setBufferSize(2048000); 
            ftp.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
            ftp.setDataTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(6000));
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            InputStream is;
            logger.trace("Retrieve file " + uri + " from FTP server...");
            is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(uri);
            ftp.completePendingCommand();
            logger.trace("FTP response was: " + ftp.getReplyString());          
            return is;
        
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e1) {
            logger.error("Server has closed connection, we will try again...");
            return getInputStreamFromURI(uri);
        } catch (ConnectException e2) {
            logger.error("The server could not be connected, let's try again...");
            return getInputStreamFromURI(uri);
        } catch (NoRouteToHostException e3) {
            logger.error("Server was not routable, let's try again...");
            return getInputStreamFromURI(uri);
        }   
    }
```

Here are the logs from the ftp container:

```
[pid 1336] OK LOGIN: Client "172.12.123.12"
[pid 1338] [ppdw] FAIL DOWNLOAD: Client "172.12.123.12", "file.csv", 366760 byte
```

What could be the problem?

So far I have tried to save the file temporarily. <s>However, this temp file is not created.</s> Another idea would be to split the file, but that didn't work either.

*Update:*

Here is the log for the small file:

```
OK DOWNLOAD: Client "172.12.123.12", "file.csv", 228893 bytes, 0.74Kbyte/sec
```

*Update#2:*
Adding the "ftp.addProtocolCommandListener" did not change anything in the logs of ftp container. Only the application logs show now:

```
Log in configured FTP server...
NOOP
200 NOOP ok.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (172,12,123,98,82,17).
RETR files/config/tpch1.properties
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file.properties (842 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
```

Comment: *"Fails"* fails as a problem description. Post some log files (both for small and large file). Exact error message. Full exception callstack (if any).

Comment: The only log message i get is the one posted of my ftp container. In java there is no exception coming up. The code just runs, waiting for the download to finish.  I will add the log for the small file to the original question.

Comment: Please do not post explanations in comments. Edit your question. + https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426062/850848

Comment: `ftp.addProtocolCommandListener` will not change the FTP server logs. It just gives you more verbose output of your Java FTP client. Is `files/config/tpch1.properties` the `file.csv` which you tried to download? Because `226 Transfer complete.` is a success message so the error would be somewhere else?